# iPhone - placing tableview within a view in another nib. Window-based

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I created a window based application, and I created a separate UITableViewController file called "HomeViewController" which right now only has a basic table.

In the MainWindow.xib file, I put a UIView in the bottom half of the screen, and I wish to put the HomeViewController tableview within this newly added UIView called "conferences".

Any suggestions as to how to push this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, usually your primary first view originates from a view controller that is loaded by the UIApplication object.  The MainWindow nib's owner is UIApplication so you probably don't want to be mucking with the MainWindow nib.  Rather, you want to muck with the view of the view controller loaded by MainWindow nib.  If you look at the view displayed in IB for MainWindow.nib, it should say which view controller's view it is loading.

So, in IB for the view of view controller being loaded by MainWindow nib, this is where you want to place your UITableView.  For purposes of this explanation, I will call this view controller, MucksViewController and associated nib, MucksView.nib.

I think what I would do, then, is drag and drop a UITableView into the view for MucksView.nib.  Position it in the bottom half of the screen, as you described.  Attach this UITableView to an IBOutlet property in MucksViewController header file.    Next, drag and drop a UIViewController object into the main window for MucksView.nib.  Make this UIViewController object's owner your HomeViewController class and also attach it to an IBOutlet property of type HomeViewController in MucksViewController's header file.

Now, in MucksViewController's class file, probably in viewDidLoad method, programmatically make the HomeViewController object the data source and delegate of the UITableView object.
But, I'm wondering, do you really need HomeViewController?  It would be cleaner just to make MucksViewController the data source and delegate.

I hope this helps and is not too confusing.

Comment: I actually realized this maybe a minute before you posted this, it was just my own stupidity hindering my abilities. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a UITableViewController, use a UIViewController which implements the tableview delegate and datasource. in your MainWindow.xib, add a standard uitableview as a subview to the view where it should be. then also drag a HomeViewController to the xib (which should now be a uiviewcontroller sub class). click on the tableview, open the inspecor, go to connections, and drag the delegate and datasource to the HomeViewController in the xib.